# upgrade project to grails 2.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, grails, groovy

i upgrade my project to grails 2.0.1 but a problem occurred:

**Problem:**

```
Command terminated with an error code (see details for output)
------System.out:-----------
| Loading Grails 2.0.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Compiling 61 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/user/workspace/myProject/grails-app/controllers/myproject/WelcomeController.groovy:
-1: The return type of java.lang.Object wait() in myproject.WelcomeController 
is incompatible with void wait() in java.lang.Object
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
------System.err:-----------
```

**Note:**

```
   i try right click --> Grails Tools -- >
   (Download source jars / & / refresh dependencies / & / grails plugin manager) 
   on my project but problem didn't solve.
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you have an action with name wait() that is build in method under java.lang.object.

you must to change the name of this method (don't forget to change name of it's gsp page)

if this doesn't solve your problem go to your project directory, show your hidden files (according to your operating system) and open .project file.

at the end of the file you will find

it must be like this:

```
<linkedResources>
   <link>
      <name>.link_to_grails_plugins</name>
      <type>2</type>
      <locationURI>GRAILS_ROOT/2.0.1/projects/myproject/plugins</locationURI>
   </link>
</linkedResources>
```

if  is GRAILS_ROOT/1.3.7/projects/...

change it to GRAILS_ROOT/2.0.1/projects/...

hope this will help you